# Windows: How do I programatically find driver number for a folder

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio, winapi

I need to update an existing C program at work to add a method to find the serial number of a drive that contains a given folder.  (I am mainly a Java developer and know nothing about low-level Windows calls in C.  I have not previously interacted programatically with Windows hardware or system configuration.)

I found a post that gives MFC code for finding the serial number of a drive, given the drive's number at http://codexpert.ro/blog/2013/10/26/get-physical-drive-serial-number-part-1/.  (The application I will be updating is not MFC, but am hoping I can modify the code from that page to work for me.)

If possible, I would like to be able to call my new method with the drive number containing a specific folder.

Is there a programmatic way to find the drive number for the folder, based on folder path?

The application will be running on Windows 7 and later.

Comment: The code you mentioned has no MFC in `GetPhysicalDriveSerialNumber` function, except for `CString`. It shouldn't be hard to replace that with C functions.

Comment: You are asking us to write your program for you?

Comment: Thanks, Barmak.  David, no, I'm not asking you to write a program for me.  I'm asking if someone has information about how to get the drive number for a folder.  If there is even a Windows command that could do it, that could help.  With that, I could try to research how to do that programatically.

Comment: @MarneeDeRider: The CodeProject article shows you how to use `DeviceIoControl()` to get a physical drive's serial number. To determine the physical drive for a folder, use `CreateFile("\\.\X:")` to open the volume (drive letter) that the folder resides on (where `X` is the drive letter), then use `DeviceIoControl(IOCTL_VOLUME_GET_VOLUME_DISK_EXTENTS)` to get the volume's drive number(s), then you can use `CreateFile("\\.\PhysicalDriveX")` to open the drive(s). This is described in the [`CreateFile()` documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858.aspx).

Comment: All of this is assuming, that the contents of a folder are stored on a single physical drive. This is not necessarily the case, for example when using certain RAID configurations, or [Dynamic Disks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363785.aspx#dynamic_disks). You'll have to decide, if this is a problem for whatever you are ultimately trying to achieve.

Comment: @iinspectable, we can assume that the contents of the folder are stored on a single physical drive for this.